# Pyspark dataframe structure in databricks (from json file)

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark, structure, databricks

I am a beginner and I am on this problem this 2 days...
I have a lot of json files and I want to insert them in a delta table.
In each I have this structure :
If no solutions :
{Field1 :"blabla, Field : "Blabla, Solutions : []}
If solutions :
{Field1 :"blabla, Field : "Blabla, Solutions : [{index : "1", street :"blabla}]}

When I try to insert it in my delta lake I have this error :
The schema of your Delta table has changed in an incompatible way since your DataFrame or
DeltaTable object was created

The problem comes from Solutions structure.
How can I deal with this problem ?
Is it possible to change the structure of Solutions when I have no solutions ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: please compare delta table definition and schema and make sure schema is not corrupted . Especially data type of the column mismatch . You can refer same issue/solution here https://groups.google.com/g/delta-users/c/578cfKcAXZA?pli=1

Comment: That doesn't help me... I don't know how to declare the fact my solutions can be empty or with data...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve it :

- Create a schema
- Import first a json file WITH Solutions.
  If my first import is with an empty array, the schema is not kept. It considers that my solutions are array of String, not an array of structType. So the other imports are in error.